# Appcelerator: Is stacking views vertically possible?

Tags: webview, view, titanium, appcelerator

I am wondering if it is possible to stack views B and C inside a view A, with layout:vertical, that scrolls over them both, like if B and C were labels? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible, exactly like you stated.... use a vertical layout for the parent view and you should be all set.